# Play audio clip each time element is added to SVG -- d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, audio, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to play an audio clip each time an element is added to my SVG using d3.js, however it only plays once. Can anyone help?

```
imgs = svg.selectAll("image")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:image")
                .attr('width', 75)
                .attr('height', 75)
                .attr('opacity', 0)
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return d[0] + "px";
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return d[1] + "px";  //Height minus data value
                })
                .attr("xlink:href", "./images/skull.png");

imgs.transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) {
            return i * 750;
        })
        .each(function(){
            audio.play();

            audio.currentTime = 0;
            if(audio.ended) {
                console.log('ended');
            }
            else {
                console.log('not ended');
            }
        })
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('opacity', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced some callback related problems with d3. But I preferred explicitly setting up some property set like I am setting x position and and during that playing the audio. It worked for me.

```
    imgs.transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) {

            return i * 1000;
        })
        .duration(1000)
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    playAudio();
                    return d[0] + "px";
                })
        .attr('opacity', 1);

  function playAudio()
  {
   audio.play();
  }
```

Comment: you can cut down the duration as per your choice..but should be greater than audio playing length. In case of further assistance just let me know.

Comment: Thanks but found what I needed, see my reply below

Comment: @user2248441: Your answer is a copy of this one!

Comment: @Nishant Not sure what you're looking at, but my answer is very different

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using the "end" event of the D3 transition.

```
imgs.transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) {
            return i * 500;
        })
        .duration(400)
        .attr('opacity', 1)
        .each("end", function(d,i){
            if(i !== 0) {
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = 0;
            }
            audio.play();
        });
```